# Throwing exception from within catch and also from finally block

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

I want to throw any exception that occurs while doing MySQL transaction to the application. But before that I want to close any resources that are in open state. But closing these resources might again generate exception which again I would want to report to application. 
The following code will make this a little clear:

```
try
{
   // connect to MySQL DB using JDBC and run different queries
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
   // throw this exception by wrapping it in another user defined exception class
}
finally
{
   try
   {
      // close resources opened in try block ( statement, connection )
   }
   catch ( Exception e )
   {
      // throw this exception by wrapping it in another user defined exception class
   }   
}
```

I want to know what is the correct way to handle this situation ( having two exception being thrown ).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of Java you are working on?

Comment: The java version I am using is 1.6.0_22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Java 7 The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

It's better explained in *Oracle Documentation* on

- [Better Resource Management with Java SE 7: Beyond Syntactic Sugar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html)

---

sample code:

```
try(  Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery() ) {
     // connection, statements and result set are automatically closed 
}
```

**Note:** A *try-with-resources* statement can have `catch` and `finally` blocks just like an ordinary `try` statement. In a *try-with-resources* statement, any `catch` or `finally` block is run after the resources declared have been **closed**.

Comment: This looks to me a promising solution. We are still using Java 6 here but I will definitely find out more about this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
try
{
   // connect to MySQL DB using JDBC and run different queries
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
   // throw this exception by wrapping it in another user defined exception class
}
finally
{
  closeMyConnection(resource);
}

protected void closeMyConnection( Resource resource ) {
  try {
    if (resource != null) {
      resource.close();
    }
  } catch( Exception ex ) {
    log( "There is some excetion", ex );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks R.T. for you help. Basically then what should happen is that any exception thrown within finally should get handled where it is thrown and the original exception ( or any other return value ) should be passed back to application. I hope this is how most applications would work. Alas I can mark only one solution as accepted. But thanks to everyone for their efforts and help.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Exception lastException = null:
try
{
   // connect to MySQL DB using JDBC and run different queries
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
   // throw this exception by wrapping it in another user defined exception class
   lastException = e;
}

if (lastException != null) {
  // you know what to do
}
```